How can I prevent WhatsApp Web from opening a new tab when a WhatsApp Web tab is already open?
Is it possible to prevent the WhatsApp Web URL from opening in a new tab if a WhatsApp Web tab is already open?
const msg = "*Greetings From "+this.previewData.unit_name+" "+this.previewData.unit_location+"* ";
const full = `${msg}\nPlease click the link below to get your receipt. \n ${url}`;
const whatsappUrl =  "https://web.whatsapp.com:/send?text=" + encodeURIComponent(full);
window.open(whatsappUrl, '_blank');```


Don't use _blank as target, but make up a name yourself. If the target context already exists, it will be reused on the next window.open call. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#target

You can use a local variable to store the reference to the open window. So that it does not open on second trigger.
const msg = "*Greetings From "+this.previewData.unit_name+" "+this.previewData.unit_location+"* ";
const full = `${msg}\nPlease click the link below to get your receipt. \n ${url}`;
const whatsappUrl =  "https://web.whatsapp.com:/send?text=" + encodeURIComponent(full);
let windowRef = null;
if(!windowRef) {
    windowRef = window.open(whatsappUrl, '_blank');
}

